# How to while loop images from directory

Tags: php, mysql, image, directory, image-uploading

Surprisingly, Google had nothing.

My old method of uploading images was storing the actual image in the database.  I'm trying to change my method to storing the photos in directories.  But I'm having troubles figuring out how to display them to the users.  I'm trying to while loop the files.  Much help is greatly appreciated.  Also, PDO is not my strong suit, trying to learn it the best I can.  Here is what I have.

```
$query6 = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE userID=$memberID";
$result6 = $db->query($query6);

while ($row6 = $result6->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

$photo = $row6['photo'];

while ($photo == true) {

echo "<img src=\"images/$memberID/$photo\">";

}

}
```

The page isn't loading at all.  Not even an error.  Your help is greatly appreciated.  Thank You!

The code does insert the photo name in database and properly upload the photo to the directories.  I only need assistance with displaying to the user.  :)

Comment: what is $memberID in your code

Comment: if (isset($photo) && $photo!="") {echo "<img src=images/$memberID/$photo>";
}

Comment: $memberID is the actual id of the member.  When a user registers, they're given an "id" via auto_increment.

Comment: did you actually have a directory with a name of memberid??

Comment: Why does the example you post hast numbers at the end of the variable names?

Comment: Yes.  I had it created if the directory didn't exist.  But it's breaking at a space in the file name. This Photo.jpg is "This".  Should I replace spaces using preg replace with underscores or something?

Comment: Long story short.  I prefer not to mix up my variables, since I use so many queries, $query and $query2 are separated.  I've never had problems with that in the past.  Is that part of variable naming rules or just bad practice?

Comment: and no, the directory name isn't memberid.  If a user's member id is 6, the directory name would be 6.  Helps to organize the photos by individual users.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear as to what you are really trying to accomplish. Just show the image to the user, or write the image to a directory and then show it. What's the correct answer.

Comment: I'm trying to show all images to the user.  Not just one.

Comment: Wow.  You're awesome.  You led me in the right direction.  I did have to replace spaces with underscore for it to work.  But I got it working.  I thank you very much.  And it seems you probably think I don't write the best code... well... I don't.  So if you have any unrelated advice feel free.  Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

close your img tag.like

```
echo "<img src=\"images/$memberID/$photo\" />";
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did know that.  Just been out of the web developing for two years.  It's not like riding a bike.  You can forget things lol.  Back to the tutorials! lol :)  I hope to take computer science in college.  All of what I know is from tutorials and forums.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($photo == true) 
{?>

    <img src="images/<? echo $memberID;?>/<?echo $photo;?>">
```